# Which http or Https link call behind gradle dependency?

Tags: android, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

In my android studio I was use following dependencies in my gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

Now I try to re-open that in android studio but it shows me failed to Resolved Error. 
My Network admin block some site that's why these dependency not work for me. 
Now  I want to access these dependency but I don't know how they connect with server , which URL call behind these dependency.

Comment: Your admin is really a bad guy! Check out logs starting from Info level if you could get some clue.

Answer (score 0):

There are more then one possible options available.

1) First of all try to add Volley as a jar dependencies from this URL: http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/mcxiaoke/volley/library/1.0.0/library-1.0.0.jar
(**This is official way to add volley**)

download Volley.jar file and paste it in **your-project\app\libs** folder and add as jar dependencies. Then rebuild your project.if this doesn't work then,

2) Try to remove  **espresso's plugin** and rebuild again.

this might be work.

Comment: Say, is it possible to call `implementation` with the direct URL to the jar/aar file? This way, If I have my own server, I could offer a semi-public way to reach it (semi because it's not a part of the popular hosts).

Answer (score 0):

We need to specify some repository where gradle can find required jars. We can directly use the maven and jcenter repository. Gradle can make call to maven & jcenter repository using `mavenCentral()` and `jcenter()`. 
In your `build.gradle` there should be something like this

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
   }  
}
```

If you click on `mavenCentral()`, you'll find this `javadoc` comment

```
 /**
 * Adds a repository which looks in the Maven central repository for dependencies. The URL used to access this repository is
 * {@value org.gradle.api.artifacts.ArtifactRepositoryContainer#MAVEN_CENTRAL_URL}. The name of the repository is
 * {@value org.gradle.api.artifacts.ArtifactRepositoryContainer#DEFAULT_MAVEN_CENTRAL_REPO_NAME}.
 *
 * <p>Examples:
 * <pre autoTested="">
 * repositories {
 *     mavenCentral()
 * }
 * </pre>
 * </p>
 *
 * @return the added resolver
 * @see #mavenCentral(java.util.Map)
 */
MavenArtifactRepository mavenCentral();
```

and by clicking on `#MAVEN_CENTRAL_URL` you find the url which is

```
  String MAVEN_CENTRAL_URL = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/";
```

Now if you repeat for `jcenter()` you'll end up with

```
https://jcenter.bintray.com/
```

So I think these are the url android find most of its libraries.